# How to calibrate map image with geo coordinates in Open Layers?

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I have an image of a map with lat/long lines (UTM grid).

How to calibrate the map in Open Layers so I can type various coordinates and have a marker on the map exactly on that position?

Answer (score 1):

It may be you can use "Raster Reprojection" feature?

https://openlayers.org/en/latest/doc/tutorials/raster-reprojection.html

There are few demos, and this one looks like that you are looking for:
https://openlayers.org/en/master/examples/reprojection-image.html

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into it!

Comment: resource has moved, the new link may be this one : https://openlayers.org/doc/tutorials/raster-reprojection.html